# Default values in Postgres view with triggered instead-of update

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I was planning on having a view with `instead of insert` trigger. There seems to be a problem with inserting a default value though.

Having the trigger set up as below, the following query fails

```
INSERT INTO v1.clients (foo) VALUES ('bar')
```

this returns a

> null value in column "is_admin" violates not-null constraint

even though the underlying `data.users` (`not null`) table has a default value set.

What I'd say happens is the view translates all missing values to `null` and the `instead of` is applied, trying to insert `null` to a `not null default false` column.

Can I somehow set up the trigger to instead of trying to insert null to insert the default value? Having `coalesce(NEW.is_admin, default)` in the relevant insert in the trigger is a syntax error. I would rather not duplicate the default value manually in trigger.

Is this supported in postgres? **What would be the best approach to split a view of two tables to those tables, while allowing default values?**

definitions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1.clients AS
    SELECT
        c.id, c.foo,
        u.id user_id, u.is_admin
    FROM data.clients c
    INNER JOIN data.users u ON u.client_id = c.id;

CREATE FUNCTION data.separate_client_user_data()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    client_id clients.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data.clients (foo) VALUES (NEW.foo) RETURNING id INTO client_id;
    INSERT INTO data.users (client_id, is_admin)
        VALUES (client_id, NEW.is_admin);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER user_data_trigger
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v1.clients
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE data.separate_client_user_data();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a trigger function, the `NEW` and `OLD` implicit parameters always contain all the fields of the underlying table or view, with `NULL` assigned to fields for which no data is available. This is the correct behaviour, otherwise you could never assign a value to a field with no data.

In case you have a field with a `NULL` value and you want to get the `DEFAULT` value upon `INSERT` instead, you should test for it prior to doing the `INSERT`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION data.separate_client_user_data() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    cid clients.id%TYPE; -- Don't use variable with same name as a column
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO data.clients (foo) VALUES (NEW.foo) RETURNING id INTO cid;
    IF NEW.is_admin IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO data.users (client_id)
            VALUES (cid);   -- Use default value for is_admin
    ELSE    
        INSERT INTO data.users (client_id, is_admin)
            VALUES (cid, NEW.is_admin);
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 8):

Late to the game, I know, but I have extra insight I want to share.

Note that, as Patrick said, the NEW variable that the TRIGGER PROCEDURE uses contains all the fields - with NULLs added for any fields that were not originally part of your INSERT statement.

As you pointed out, the underlying table has a default value for the `is_admin` field, and unfortunately that default value doesn't get a chance to be seen, because the NEW variable already has NEW.is_admin = NULL.

However, I want to point out a different solution from Patrick's.  It's true that you can hand-code the IF checks (essentially re-implementing the default value logic!) in your plpgsql function.  But this may feel non-optimal from a DRY perspective.  Here was the key for me when I had your problem:

**TL/DR**

The default values of the **view itself** are honored when building the NEW variable.  Therefore if you do `ALTER TABLE <view_name> ALTER is_admin SET DEFAULT false` it should cause `false` to be passed in to `NEW.is_admin`, instead of `NULL`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this!